Merging of parameters/variables arrays in Azure Pipelines
Given 2 parameters of type "array" in some reusable template:
parameters:
  - name: stageDependsOn
    type: object
    default: []
  - name: _defaultDependsOn
    type: object
    default: ['must_have_stage']

... how to concatenate them into a single array at use-place? Looking for something like this, but concat does not exist:
- stage: targetStage
  displayName: Target stage
  dependsOn: ${{ concat(parameters._defaultDependsOn, parameters.stageDependsOn) }}


It turned out there is no need to explicitly merge for achieving the goal.
The following works:
- stage: targetStage
  displayName: Target stage
  dependsOn:
    - ${{ parameters._defaultDependsOn }}
    - ${{ parameters.stageDependsOn }}

as if it was a hard-coded list:
- stage: targetStage
  displayName: Target stage
  dependsOn:
    - must_have_stage
    - stage1_from_stageDependsOn
    - stage2_from_stageDependsOn
    - etc_from_stageDependsOn


Currently, the expressions in Azure DevOps can't concatenate two parameters of type array into a single array.  You can request a feature for Azure DevOps here to help the feature better.
Workaround of the issue:
You can define one parameter with both the default stages and other stages. You just need to keep the must_have_stage there. Then you can add or remove the other stages.
trigger:
- none
parameters:
  - name: stageDependsOn
    type: object
    default:
      - must_have_stage
      - AAA
      - BBB
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest
stages:
- stage: must_have_stage
  jobs:
  - job: A1
    steps:
      - script: echo Hello, world!

- stage: AAA
  jobs:
  - job: A1
    steps:
      - script: echo Hello, world!
- stage: BBB
  jobs:
  - job: A1
    steps:
      - script: echo Hello, world!

- stage: targetStage
  dependsOn: ${{ parameters.stageDependsOn }}
  jobs:
  - job: A1
    steps:
      - script: echo Hello, world!


I guess with this code you will get one single string, where each stage name is delimited with _. But I need a new array object, containing all elements from both input arrays.

Hi @Kirill, thanks for your reminder. Yes, the stage name will be a string due to the format command. Now I understand that you want a new array object. It seems that there is no command to concatenate two array type parameters into a single array in yaml. I tried to do this using some scripting, however, the dependsOn field should be defined before the pipeline runs, so it can't use the array from the script. The workaround I could find was to avoid concatenating two parameters and just define one.

Hi @Miao Tian-MSFT. It turned out, that there is no special action needed from your side to merge 2 lists at "use-site". You can pass list1 and list2 as an elements of a "use-site" list and they either will get implicitly flattened, or Azure Pipelines is fine accepting "list of lists" for dependsOn. See my own reply to this question.

Hi @Kirill, oh yes, your answer is perfect. No more action is needed, and I didn't realize that we can use "list of lists" in this way. Thanks for sharing it!

I was not sure if I can accept my answer because the question was about "merging", but I was in doubt if there is a merging actually happening, or dependsOn is just fine with accepting "a list of lists". I checked the doubt by passing a list of lists explicitly to dependsOn and as a result Azure produces an error saying: "A sequence was not expected" (where "sequence" is an explicit nested list). So I am pretty sure that implicit merging happens in my answer and I will accept it.

Yes, it seems the implicit merging happens. Your answer is correct for the question.
